# Is it possible to use the `verbatim` environment in a dot2tex node?

Tags: verbatim

Is it possible to use the verbatim environment (i.e. `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`) in a [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) node? If so, please could you provide a MWE?

---

Update: this is the closest I've got so far:

```
digraph g {
d2tdocpreamble = "\usepackage{varwidth} \usepackage{verbatim} \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}";
graph [ rankdir = "TB" ];
node  [ style="rounded,bold,filled" fillcolor="azure" shape = "box" ];

assume_git         [ texlbl="\begin{varwidth}{30em}We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim or OS X, enter the following at the command prompt:\\\verb|echo '*.swp'      >> .gitignore|\\\verb|echo '.DS\_Store'  >> .gitignore|\end{varwidth}" ];

START              -> assume_git;
}
```

And this is the output from turning it into a PDF via the command `dot2tex --crop --margin 1em --autosize dot2tex_test_006_mwe.dot > dot2tex_test_006_mwe.tex; pdflatex dot2tex_test_006_mwe.tex`:

[image]

This is unsatisfactory in at least two ways:

1. instead of

   ```
   \\\verb|echo '*.swp'      >> .gitignore|\\\verb|echo '.DS\_Store'  >> .gitignore|
   ```

   I would much prefer to have been able to use

   ```
   \begin{verbatim}
   echo '*.swp'      >> .gitignore
   echo '.DS_Store'  >> .gitignore
   \end{verbatim}
   ```

   to avoid the need for unnecessary markup for every newline in the code block, but the latter generated the following errors:

   ```
   ERROR    Failed to process input
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/dot2tex/dot2tex.py", line 2928, in main
       s =  conv.convert(dotdata)
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/dot2tex/dot2tex.py", line 794, in convert
       return self.do_preview_preproc()
     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/dot2tex/dot2tex.py", line 1105, in do_preview_preproc
       hp,dp,wt = pp.texdims[name]
   KeyError: 'assume_git'
   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/MacPorts 2011_5) restricted \write18 enabled.
   entering extended mode
   (./dot2tex_test_006_mwe.tex
   LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
   Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, czech, slovak, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, basque, french, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, german, ngerman, swissgerman, italian, polish, portuguese, spanish, catalan, galician, loaded.
   )
   *
   ```
2. The `\\\verb|...|` approach in the MWE does not render the code verbatim. Even my short example has the following problems:

   - in order to avoid error messages, I had to add a backslash in front of the underscore, but now the backslash is rendered. So I need a way to render *just* an underscore;
   - the straight single quote marks around `*.swp` and `.DS\_Store` have been replaced by right single quote marks;
   - one member of each pair of greater-than signs has disappeared.

Comment: `echo "It's explained on dot2tex man page"; echo 'digraph G {a_0 [texlbl="\verb|XY|"] a_1 [texlbl="$x$"] a_0 -> a_1}' > tmp.dot ; dot2tex tmp.dot > tmp.tex; pdflatex tmp`

Comment: Interesting. I can't find the example you gave in the [dot2tex documentation](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/), nor in [the repo](http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/source/search?q=verb&origq=verb&btnG=Search+Trunk). `man dot2tex` doesn't work for me - although I used easy_install, so wasn't expecting it to work - but I can't see any documentation in the latest ZIP file either ([dot2tex-2.8.7.zip](http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/downloads/detail?name=dot2tex-2.8.7.zip)) that includes your example. Please could you tell me more about where you found that explanation? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't write the example I gave was on the man page but the mechanism _is_ explained on the man page, cause that's where I found it (today).

Comment: Your example works, but both this: `echo 'digraph G {a_0 [texlbl="\begin{verbatim}XY\end{verbatim}"] a_1 [texlbl="$x$"] a_0 -> a_1}' > tmp.dot ; dot2tex tmp.dot > tmp.tex; pdflatex tmp` and also this: `echo 'digraph G {d2tdocpreamble = "\usepackage{verbatim}"; a_0 [texlbl="\begin{verbatim}XY\end{verbatim}"] a_1 [texlbl="$x$"] a_0 -> a_1}' > tmp.dot ; dot2tex tmp.dot > tmp.tex; pdflatex tmp` fail with the message **! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.** So I'd be grateful for a fuller answer :)

Comment: I should add that I'm particularly interested in being able to put multi-line code blocks or ASCII art into dot2tex nodes, preferably within a single `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` pair (or equivalent), instead of having to use `\verb|foo|\\\verb|bar|`, because the more lines the block contains, the more cumbersome the latter becomes.

Comment: I don't know anything about dot2tex, nor can I run it (I think), but the `verbatimbox` package allows you to stuff verbatim into a box, and then (immediately or later) recall the box.  Perhaps that would help you achieve your goal.

Comment: @sampablokuper Did the suggestion of Steven work?

Comment: @masu, I don't think I tried it, sorry. (By that point - almost a year after I'd asked the question - I'd moved on to other things.) It sounds plausible, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the round shapes, independently on what text I add.

However, the solution is to use more lines.

```
digraph g {
d2tdocpreamble = "
  \usepackage{varwidth}
  \usepackage{verbatim}
  \usepackage{upquote}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
";
graph [ rankdir = "TB" ];
node  [ style=rounded, fillcolor=azure];

assume_git [ texlbl="\begin{varwidth}{30em}
  We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against
  accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim or OS X, enter the following
  at the command prompt:
  \begin{verbatim}
  echo '*.swp'      >> .gitignore
  echo '.DS\_Store'  >> .gitignore
  \end{verbatim}
  \end{varwidth}"
 ];

START              -> assume_git;
}
```

[image]